# Shut down JVM when Firebase emulator closes

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, jvm, firebase-tools

`firebase-tools` is an NPM package that uses the JVM. It includes an `emulators:start` command which fires up the JVM, and it has the JVM use some ports (defined in settings) for the emulators' input/output.

I use MacOS. I use a VSCode terminal to start/end the emulators, and define the details of how to start using an NPM script. Like this:

```
npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,auth,firestore,database --import ./db-temp
```

In other words, run the `build` script, then start some emulator services.

So when running the emulators, I:

1. Open a terminal,
2. Navigate to the folder containing the script
3. Run the script (`npm run serve`)

This gives me a convenient place to get feedback from the emulators for things like errors, network activity, etc.

If I close VSCode using VSCode's X button, everything in VSCode is immediately shut down. When the terminal is closed, the JVM doesn't detect this and quit: it keeps running. Then when I open VSCode and try running my script again, it tells me that the port normally used by the emulators is still open, because the JVM didn't shut down properly. So I have to track down the JVM process, Force Quit it, and then everything works fine.

To shut the emulators down properly, I have to go to the terminal process running the emulators, press ALT+C to close the process, and then close VSCode. This extra step is inconvenient, and easily forgotten.

Can I convince the JVM to shut down when its originating process terminates via a configuration option? I looked through the configuration options on my local machine via `java` and `java -x`, and didn't see anything promising, but I am sure that there are people who know much more about Java than I do.

The Firebase emulator has [an environment variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#specifying_java_options) available for Java configuration.

I would be open to other options if available: telling VSCode to automatically shut down terminals properly before exiting, for example.

Or must this be handled by `firebase-tools` itself, perhaps via a [ShutdownHook](https://dzone.com/articles/know-jvm-series-2-shutdown)?

Comment: You cannot do that in general. It's the responsibility of the parent process who launched the JVM to handle this situation, that is `firebase-tools` itself. I'd open an issue with the maintainer of the project (or search for an existing one): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Answer (score 0):

After a little conversation with Firebase and some troubleshooting, I learned a few things:

1. This issue only occurs when running `firebase emulators:start --only firestore,database`: when they run together, the Firestore process never closes. Start either one by itself and everything closes fine. This leads me to suspect that this is a bug.
2. This is reproducible outside VSCode, leading me to suspect that the issue has nothing to do with VSCode.

I filed https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4657. We'll see how it turns out.