# Firebase emulator prevent log window from opening

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

When I run the `firebase emulators:start` command on Windows 10, it opens up a console with what looks like a java program outputting log events from the emulator suite. Is there any way to prevent this window from opening?

Thanks!

edit: This window doesn't even close after emulators:exec finishes its command, preventing a proper cleanup.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: This is on Windows.

Comment: Right now I'm killing the port after emulators:exec, but I don't like having a window pop up when I'm doing tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all , this link can help you on how to shutdown correctly the JVMs:
[Shut down JVM when Firebase emulator closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72606370/shut-down-jvm-when-firebase-emulator-closes)
Since you're talking about Java console , then you should use javaw.exe instead of java.exe ! Javaw prevents logs from appearing in console . I'm not an expert of firebase but I believe there's a config file in which there's a call to Java binary which launches the JVM and finally change the java by javaw

Comment: Since asking this question I've migrated to Linux, where the issue isn't present, so I haven't tested this answer, but `javaw` vs `java` seems like a solid lead, so the bounty is yours :)

Comment: Great , thank you Nathan :) Well Congrats for moving to Linux

Comment: Thanks! I've used it before but it's been a while. It's like a breath of fresh air, so much easier to program on than windows, and looks more aesthetic/modern too now that it's set up.

Comment: That sounds great ! Happy for you brother , good luck